# Displaying a json string to html div

Tags: html, json, angularjs

To access the information in a  tag in a list, how would I do so? Could I use dot notation? Javascript is being used in the backend and javascript is being used in the frontend.

HTML:

```
<div>{{ GameData }}</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
{
    "player_stat_summary": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "stats": {
                "id": 1,
                "average_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "total_minion_kills": 0,
                "max_champions_killed": 0,
                "total_champion_kills": 0,
                "average_champions_killed": 0,
                "average_num_deaths": 0,
                "max_node_capture": 0,
                "max_objective_player_score": 0,
                "total_neutral_minions_killed": 0,
                "max_assists": 0,
                "average_combat_player_score": 0,
                "max_node_capture_assist": 0,
                "average_objective_player_score": 0,
                "max_team_objective": 0,
                "total_assists": 0,
                "average_node_capture": 0,
                "average_total_player_score": 0,
                "average_team_objective": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize": 0,
                "max_node_neutralize": 0,
                "average_node_neutralize_assist": 0,
                "average_assists": 0,
                "max_total_player_score": 0,
                "max_combat_player_score": 0,
                "total_turrets_killed": 0,
                "total_node_neutralize": 0,
                "total_node_capture": 0
            },
            "player_stat_summary_type": "Coop",
            "wins": 100,
            "losses": 0
        }
    ],
    "time_stamp": "2015-05-22T15:54:43.069814Z",
    "summoner_id": 0
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by Javascript is used in backend ? and the notation you have used in the html div tag (the double curly brackets) comes from angularjs notation .

Comment: Do you mean noje.js + angular.js ?
what exactly are you asking?

Comment: If I understand the question:
you can use the dot notation like this... 
"GameData.player_stat_summary.id" in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot notation as well as string notation. For example, in the given data, you can access the first object of the data as

```
GameData.player_stat_summary[0]
```

OR

```
GameData["player_stat_summary"][0]
```

You can any property of "player_stat_summary" as:

```
GameData.player_stat_summary[0].id
```

OR

```
GameData["player_stat_summary"][0]["id"]
```

Similarly more hierarchy can be accessed.